# Evaluating a specific letter of a string defined in a derived type in Fortran90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I would like to evaluate if the 3rd letter of variable **myline** is **'C'** or not.

I try this:

```
program main

    implicit none

    type line
        integer                     :: count    = 5
        character(len=48)           :: list     = 'ABCDE'
    end type

    type(line)                      :: myline
    character(len=1)                :: letter   = 'C'

    write(*,*) myline%count, myline%list

    if(myline%list(3) == letter) then
        write(*,*) 'TRUE'
    else
        write(*,*) 'FALSE'
    end if

end program
```

But I get:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gfortran8 -mcmodel=medium -fcheck=all -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib/gcc8 -o test test.f90
test.f90:15:15:

  if(myline%list(3) == letter) then
               1
Error: Syntax error in IF-expression at (1)
test.f90:17:5:

  else
     1
Error: Unexpected ELSE statement at (1)
test.f90:19:4:

  end if
    1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
```

I am using gfortran (gcc8) and the Fortran 90 standard.

Comment: For completeness with the linked questions, the character being a component of a derived type does not affect how the substring is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fortran, a character substring reference always needs a start and end position. So what you want here is `myline%list(3:3)`.

You can omit the end position (retaining the colon), for example `(3:)`, and that means the rest of the string. Similarly you can omit the start position and it means from the first character `(:3)`.

As a suggestion, `letter` would be better declared with the `parameter` attribute as it is a constant, but what you have would work.